# change add to cart button link

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm new to WordPress and the WooCommerce plugin. I'm creating a plugin to change the add to cart button link if it hits a desired stock quantity.

For example if stock qty is above 50, I would like to change the link for special payment.

I've searched for hours in the internet and found no solution or idea on how to do it.
Is it possible? Can you give me ideas on how to start and implement it.

Comment: _"Is it possible?"_ ... sure, that this is the question?

Comment: hmmm...my question was edited. I was also asking some ideas on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly just figured out how to do most of this today.

To accomplish your goal, you will need to hook into one of the url filters found in **woocommerce/templates/loop/add-to-cart.php** between **lines 30 - 53**, take advantage of the global **$product** variable, and the [**get_stock_quantity**](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#_get_stock_quantity) function.

Let's say you're only worried about Simple Products (no variations), then I believe that this is how you would handle it:

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_url', 'add_special_payment_link' );

function add_special_payment_link( $link ) {
    global $product;

    // If the stock quantity is less than 50, don't modify the link
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 50 ) {
        return $link;
    }

    // Write your code here to come up with the special payment link
    $link = 'http://wordpress.org/';  // You know, your link, not WordPress

    return $link;
}

// Since WooCommerce's JavaScript uses AJAX to add an item to a cart, we need to remove
// the class 'add_to_cart_button' from the button when the stock is greater than 50
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_class', 'remove_add_to_cart_class' );

function remove_add_to_cart_class( $class ) {
    global $product;

    // If the stock quantity is less than 50, don't modify the class
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 50 ) {
        return $class;
    }

    // Specify a custom class or just return an empty string
    return '';
}
```

Now I haven't tested this code (So only use it on a test site), but taking into consideration what I did earlier today, and assuming that [**get_stock_quantity**](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#_get_stock_quantity) function actually works, that code should at least give you a good start.

Let me know how it goes or if you have any questions for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cant get get_stock_quantity. It did change the link though but somewhat not firing it. My guess it has a class that triggers the javascript for adding the product to the cart. I have found a solution not that good but somehow it does what I want to do. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I forgot that the JavaScript targets all buttons with the class 'add_to_cart_button'. I'll add the fix for that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research, i found a somewhat weird solution but somehow works. I used the woocommerce_is_purchasble hook. It passes 2 parameters `is_purchasable` and `object` (`WC_Product`) Which I can now get the product total number of stock.

Here's what I did.

```
function order_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $object) {
    if($object->get_total_stock() > 50){
        echo '<a style="margin-bottom: 10px;" href="" class="button">Call to purchase</a>';
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'order_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
```

The echo displays the button linking to my desired page for special payment.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to how I am modifying the add to cart URL in my Name Your Price plugin... which I copied almost exactly from one of Mike Jolley's premium plugins.

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_url', 'wpa104168_tadd_special_payment_link' );

function wpa104168_tadd_special_payment_link( $link ) {
    global $product;

    // If the stock quantity is greater than 50, modify the link
    if( $product->get_stock_quantity() > 50 ) {
        $link = 'http://wordpress.org/';  
        $product->product_type = 'modified';  
    }

    return $link;
}
```

Temporarily changing the `product_type` will disabled the Ajax add to cart functionality.